What is a comprehensive list of all the different arrows in Category Theory? (Dashed, Double Arrow, etc...)
I realize there's different conventions for the use of arrows in a graph for Category Theory.
Does anyone have a "semi"-comprehensive list of all the arrows?

Is this mostly a typographical question?  Otherwise I'm trying to understand what "use of an arrow" is.

Even before I learned any category theory, the "types" of arrows I was taught with were
$A\to B$: a map from $A$ into $B$
$A\rightarrowtail B$: an injective map
$A\twoheadrightarrow B$: a surjective map
$A\hookrightarrow B $: the inclusion map of $A$ into $B$, where $A\subseteq B$.
After learning some category theory (or maybe just some homological stuff) you'd start seeing dashed arrows
$A\dashrightarrow B$ when the existence of the map is "new" in the diagram, a consequence of some relevant property.
In category theory, you also see $\implies$ style arrows to denote natural transformations between functors in diagrams like these, which I won't try to reproduce here.
I'm sure there are more, especially decorated variants, but it seems like a list like that might be extremely long.
At any rate, I think it is unimportant to concern oneself too much with notational conventions like this. The real challenge in category theory is getting your head around the layers. (E.g., there are arrows between objects, but functors can be objects in a category, and they have their own (called natural transformations). But then natural transformations can be objects in a category, and there are arrows between those... etc.)




Arrow
Meaning




$\longrightarrow$
morphism


$\hookrightarrow$
monomorphism / embedding*


$\twoheadrightarrow$
epimorphism


$\xrightarrow{\sim}$
isomorphism / weak equivalence*


$\Longrightarrow$
natural transformation / $2$-morphism*


$\looparrowright$
relation / profunctor*


$\dashrightarrow$
emphasize existence of a morphism



Not complete, but that's a start.
*Depends on the context
